# CapsPageMenu API Called on tap Tab Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new in IOS and creating an app. I am working with the CapsPageMenu iOS objective-c library. I am seeing that on a Tap,  For eg: if I have Tab1,Tab2 ,Tab3 and Tab4 and I am currently on Tab1 then when I click on Tab4, I see that Tab2's API are also being called..This is most probably since the Tab2 view can be seen scrolling horizontally for a second.. However I need to fetch data from a web service on each of the tabs when they are loaded. Hence this leads to unnecessary network calls.

How can I ensure that the web service calls are only executed for a tab when that tab is actually loaded and not on scrolling past?

**Parent ViewController CapsPageMenu**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.title = @"Point History";
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[ApplicationDesignClass sharedInstance].appLayoutDesign.appHeader._headerLabel._textColor}];

    ViewController *controller1 = [[AllViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AllViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller1.title = @"ALL";
    controller1.historyType = HistoryTypeAll;

    ViewController *controller2 = [[AllViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AllViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller2.title = @"ADDED";
    controller2.historyType = HistoryTypeAdded;

    ViewController *controller3 = [[AllViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AllViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller3.title = @"USED";
    controller3.historyType = HistoryTypeUsed;

    ViewController *controller4 = [[AllViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AllViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller4.title = @"UNUSED";
    controller4.historyType = HistoryTypeUnused;

    NSArray *controllerArray = @[controller1, controller2, controller3, controller4];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionScrollMenuBackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionUnselectedMenuItemLabelColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectedMenuItemLabelColor: [UIColor lightgraycolor],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionViewBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:20.0/255.0 green:20.0/255.0 blue:20.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionSelectionIndicatorColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionBottomMenuHairlineColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:70.0/255.0 green:70.0/255.0 blue:70.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0],
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuHeight: @(40.0),
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionMenuItemWidth: @(70.0),
                                 CAPSPageMenuOptionCenterMenuItems: @(NO)
                                 };

    _pageMenu = [[CAPSPageMenu alloc] initWithViewControllers:controllerArray frame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) options:parameters];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageMenu.view];
}
```

**Child ViewController**

> **Note:- For eg: if I have AllTab, AddedTab ,UsedTab and UnusedTab and I am currently on AllTab then when I click on UnusedTab I see that AddedTab to data show but I want UnusedTab data show**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, HistoryType){
  HistoryTypeAll,
  HistoryTypeAdded,
  HistoryTypeUsed,
  HistoryTypeUnused
};
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) HistoryType historyType;
@end
```

Comment: Give the link of library.

Comment: @SaurabhJain This is the link https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu